# Derivative of Complex Exponential

Tags: complex-numbers

I would like help with this problem.

Prove this is true by using complex analysis. This problem appeared in my workbook and there appears to be no solution in the back.

$$\frac{d}{dx}e^{tx} = te^{tx}.$$

Edit: I think I am supposed to use chain rule?

Comment: So $x$ and $t$ are complex numbers and $d/dx$ denotes complex derivative? Yes, this follows for instance from the chain rule.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I wasn't sure if using the chain rule was complex analysis or just calculus.
Edit: It says I need to use a different formula or method to prove this true.

Comment: Possibly Euler's formula?

Comment: I feel uncomfortable trying to intuit the desires of whoever is asking you this question, but perhaps they want you to use something like Cauchy's integral formula?

Comment: @AntonioVargas Presumably they wanted a weaker result to be used, not a stronger one.

Comment: @Justin You should probably mention what you've learned so far. The chain rule is by far the most straightforward way to this. If this is an exercise in a book, then perhaps tell us what was covered in the chapter where the question was posed. We're not going to be able to guess how you want the problem solved.

Comment: Hi @EuYu, we've started proving trigonometric functions with Euler's formula: ei t = cos t + i sin t
I think this is how I should prove this to be true. By taking the derivative of cos(t) + isin(t) ?

Comment: @Justin Presumably you've only covered Euler's formula for _real_ numbers?

Comment: @Justin The question's title is not very helpful. Perhaps you could change it? Maybe something like "Derivative of the complex exponential"

Comment: Your answer will also depend on how you've defined the exponential function. If $e^x = e^{\operatorname{re}(x)}e^{i\operatorname{im}(x)}$, the answer will be different than if $e^x = \sum \frac{x^n}{n!}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind, I will use the complex number letters I am used to.

So a complex function of the complex variable is holomorphic at $z_0$ if 
$$
\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}
$$
exists in $\mathbb{C}$. In this case, it is denoted by $f'(z_0)$.

This notion obeys the usual rules you are used to for derivatives of real functions of the real variable. In particular, there is a chain rule. But note there is much much more structure on holomorphic functions, than on differentiable real functions of the real variable.

So the function you are considering is
$$
g(z):=e^{uz}.
$$
This is the composition $g=\exp\circ f$ with $f(z)=uz$. Now $\exp$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ with derivative equal to itself (this is a fact which follows from the definition of $\exp$ as the sum of the series $\sum_{n\geq 0} z^n/n!$), and $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ with derivative equal to $u$ (this is easy from the definition).

Now by the chain rule, $g$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ and
$$
g'(z)=\exp'(f(z))f'(z)=e^{uz}u.
$$