# Complex functions whose derivative is itself

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

If $f$ is a real function whose derivative is itself, then it is not difficult to see that it is of the form $f(x)=ce^{x}$, $c \in \mathbb{R}$.
(If $c=0$, then $f=0$).

Indeed, assume that $g(x)$ satisfies $g'(x)=g(x)$.
Take $h(x):=g(x)e^{-x}$.
Then by the Chain Rule we have:
$h'(x)=g'(x)e^{-x}-g(x)e^{-x}$.
Since $g(x)=g'(x)$ we obtain that $h'(x)=0$.
Then $h(x)=c$, for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$.
Therefore, $c=h(x)=g(x)e^{-x}$, so $g(x)=ce^{x}$.

> Does the same proof (with adjustments) hold for complex functions, namely,
> if $g'(z)=g(z)$, then $g(z)=ce^{iz}$, $c \in \mathbb{C}$?

See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316535/derivative-of-complex-exponential) question.

Thank you very much!

Comment: The same proof works in $\Bbb C$ for complex differentiable functions. Only the factor $i$ in the exponent is wrong, it should be $g(z) = c e^z$.

Comment: @MartinR, thank you for your comment and correction.

Comment: another fun way is to notice that complex differentiable are analytic and then to use the power series to get $a_n=(n+1)a_{n+1}, n \ge 0$ so if $a_0=c$ then $a_n=c/n!$

Comment: @Conrad, thank you for your comment.

Comment: @Conrad You need to assume that $g$ is analytic on $z = 0$, otherwise need some extra fix. The OP probably wants to say that $g$ is entire but it is not mentioned.

Comment: @WhatsUp the relation $f'=f$ is linear so wlog we can assume it holds on a small disc centered at zero (otherwise translate); the subtler point is that complex differentiable functions  are analytic so the power series trick works

Comment: @WhatsUp, thank you. I do not mind if $g$ is not entire. $g$ could be holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ minus a finite set (like quotient of two polynomials).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, Martin R and Conrad in the comments are correct. The proof works exactly the same for complex functions, since the product rule is the same, and the exponential function has the same differentiability properties in the complex numbers. And as Conrad pointed out, this is also easy to see with the Maclaurin expansion.